# Djano annotate with subtract operation returns None when the subtrahend is None

Tags: python, django

My objective is to get the balance for a billing instance by subtracting the payments posted within the period. In my Billing model, I have a backlog field that contains the backlogs from previous period. The Billing model has m2m relationship with Payment model through PaidBills model.

In my queryset:
'''

```
qs = Billing.objects.filter(
            bill_batch=prev_batch, balance__gt=0).annotate(
            payment=Sum('paidbills__amount_paid', filter=Q(
                paidbills__pay_period=batch.period))).order_by(
            'reservation__tenant__name', 'reservation__apt_unit').only(
                'id', 'bill_batch', 'reservation')
    
qs = qs.annotate(new_bal=F('backlog') - F('payment'))
```

'''

The result is correct when the expression F('payment') contains a value, but will give a result None when F('payment') returns None. I have tried to replace the expression F('payment') with any fixed value, say 5000, and it worked as expected.

How to go about this? (Django 3.2.7, Python 3.9.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but [`Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) should do the job when the sum aggregation is None.

```py
from django.db.models import Sum, Value

qs = Billing.objects.filter(bill_batch=prev_batch, balance__gt=0) \
    .annotate(
        payment=Coalesce(
            Sum('paidbills__amount_paid', filter=Q(paidbills__pay_period=batch.period)),
            Value(0)
        )
    ) \
    .order_by('reservation__tenant__name', 'reservation__apt_unit') \
    .only('id', 'bill_batch', 'reservation')
```

Comment: Thank you @Scratch'N'Purr, you gave the solution. Though, the Value part has to be modified by providing an output_field, say Value(0, DecimalField()).. Thank you so much, I surely will come back to this when I will have complied with the 15 reputations required to cast a vote.